# How to attach the debugger as soon as a file is double-clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

As most applications, mine opens files in 2 ways:

(1) Via the "File | Open" menu. This code is fully debugged.

(2) By double-clicking a file whose extension is associated to my application. This part needs some debugging.

What is the process to debug the latter program execution path?

Is there a way to place a statement like: `CallDebugger();` ???

TIA

Comment: Sounds like you want `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by setting your application to Launch the Debugger Automatically.

> To setup an application to launch the debugger automatically
>
> 1. Start the Registry Editor (`regedit`).
> 2. In the Registry Editor, open the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder`.
> 3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`.
> 4. In the **Image File Execution Options** folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug, such as *myapp.exe*. If you cannot find the application you want to debug:
>
>    - Right-click the **Image File Execution Options** folder, and on the shortcut menu, click `New Key`.
>    - Right-click the new key, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
>    - Edit the key name to the name of your application; *myapp.exe*, in this example.
> 5. Right-click the *myapp.exe* folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New String Value**.
> 6. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
> 7. Change the name to debugger.
> 8. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Modify**. 
>      The **Edit String** dialog box appears.
> 9. In the **Value** data box, type **vsjitdebugger.exe**.
> 10. Click **OK**.
> 11. From the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.
> 12. The directory containing *vsjitdebugger.exe* must be in your system path. To add it to the system path, follow these steps:
>
>     - Open the **Control Panel** in Classic view, and double-click **System**.
>     - Click **Advanced System Settings**.
>     - In **System Properties**, click the **Advanced** tab.
>     - On the **Advanced** tab, click **Environment Variables**.
>     - In the **Environment Variables** dialog box, under **System variables**, select **Path**, then click the **Edit** button.
>     - In the **Edit System Variable** dialog box, add the directory to the **Variable value** box. Use a semicolon to separate it from other entries in the list.
>     - Click **OK** to close the **Edit System Variable** dialog box.
>     - Click **OK** to close the **Environment Variables** dialog box.
>     - Click **OK** to close the **System Properties** dialog box.
>
> Now, use any method to start your application. Visual Studio will start and load the application.

*Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx*

**Note**:

You may need to run your application `As Administrator` to succesfully launch the debugger.